# iOS UISearchBar with a diffrent Search result TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, filter, uisearchbar

I am not filtering through a UITabeView data, i want to filter through firebase usernames, display the results i get on a temporary UITableView once i select one of the Temporary UITableView data it adds to the initial UITableView. I know how to query firebase, i know how to populate or add item to a UITableView. I just need something like a popover Temporary UITableView that holds the filter of the search results.

I tried using PopOver,

**What i have currently have, but its not solving my problem**

```
let popOver = navController.popoverPresentationController
    popOver?.delegate = self
    popOver?.sourceView = self.view
    //popOver?.sourceRect = CGRect(x:0, y: 0,width: self.view.frame.width,height: self.view.frame.height)
    popOver?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is what i want to implement.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for UISearchController at  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller ?  Let us know what you've already tried.

Comment: @SonofaBeach i already tried something, let me add to what i have, i am not filtering through a UITabeView data, i want to filter through firebase usernames, display the results i can on a temporary UITableView once i select one of the Temporary UITableView data it adds to the initial UITableView